# Link from another page element to a specific data-filter

Tags: javascript, html, filter

I have a HTML portfolio page that has filtering attribute

```
                    <ul class="portfolio-filters list-inline">
                        <li class="filter active" data-filter="all">All</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter="webdesign">Web Design</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter="responsive">Responsive</li>
                        <li class="filter" data-filter="wordpress">Wordpress</li>
                    </ul>
```

And I have another HTML page that has some services. example of one of my codes in the other page:

```
                <div>
                    <i><a href="#" class="fa fa-code"></a></i>
                    <div>
                    <h4>Web Design</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

What I want is when user click on this service icon for example, it will redirect the user to the webdesign filter of the portfolio page.

I tried many ways like adding link portfolio.html?filter=webdesign to the a href of the service icon but it didn't work.

Comment: Hello Soso and welcome to Stackoverflow. What have you tried so far? You could pass the filter as URL query parameter and hide  the divs that are not targeted using basic Javascript and CSS.

Comment: @Sumi Strassle Thank you so much for welcoming. I just tried many ways related to html coding, like the one that Tobias Boertz used. Can you please clarify your solution by writing js code if possible? sorry I don't have much background about js coding.

Comment: Please keep in mind Stackoverflow is a knowledget sharing platform. You should follow a few tutorials on Javascript, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should follow a few tutorials on HTML5, CSS 3 and Javascript.

I made a basic version in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/sumi1985/pen/rNVPNMR?editors=1011). Please note I'm using the [URLSearchParams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) which is not supported in IE and other older browser. Also, I'm using [Ecmascript 6](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp).

What does the algorithm do?

1. Check the URL, is there a filter parameter (as in `http://.../somewhere?filter=wordpress`)
2. If not, do nothing and show everything, otherwise,
3. get all the content that has a `filter` class
4. display the content that match
5. hide the rest.

The crux of the algorithm lies in the getting of the query parameters, then it's a matter of looping over a collection and changing the `style`'s `display` attribute (see [the documentation for the display attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp))

```js
// 1. get URL query param (does not work on IE, AFAIK)
const url = new URL(window.location.href)
const currentFilter = url.searchParams.get('filter')

// we only filter stuff if a filter is provided
if (currentFilter != null) {

  // 2. collect all filters
  const collection = document.getElementsByClassName('filter')

  // 3. traverse the collection, hide what's not of interest, show the rest
  for (let item of collection) {
    if (item.classList.contains(currentFilter)) {
      item.style.display = 'block'
      break
    }

    item.style.display = 'none'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you. Give your li tags specific id's:

```
<ul class="portfolio-filters list-inline">
  <li class="filter active" data-filter="all" id="all-filter">All</li>
  <li class="filter" data-filter="webdesign" id="webdesign-filter">Web Design</li>
  <li class="filter" data-filter="responsive" id="responsive-filter">Responsive</li>
  <li class="filter" data-filter="wordpress" id="wordpress-filter">Wordpress</li>
</ul>
```

Then you can just link to the specific id:

```
<div>
  <i><a href="portfolio.html/#webdesign-filter" class="fa fa-code"></a></i>
  <div>
    <h4>Web Design</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Else you would have to use javascript I guess.

Comment: After many tries with writing html codes Yes I guess it needs Javascript specific code. Thank you so much for trying.